# defining and using your own functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, user-defined-functions

If I have defined a function I expect to use in most of my programs, where do I store it so that I can just import it without having to have it in the same folder as my program?

Also when should I call such functions as opposed to importing them? (I am not sure what the correct terminology is) i.e.
When would you set up a function so that you use it by:

```
myFunction()
```

And when would you set it up so that you use by :

```
import myFunction as mf
...
mf.blahblah
```

Comment: You don't always have to give aliases, which is what your second example is doing. In some cases, giving aliases could confuse readers. You'd use an alias if the pre-defined name was either too verbose to be practical in production code, or if it's not descriptive enough to be easily maintainable. Importing every function you use, with an alias as you're doing, would be tedious.

Comment: that's very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

Access modifier for your function : public

Now you can create instance of the class. And you can easily use same function from everywhere.

Comment: Where do I put the access modifier?

Comment: You can create like this... class example { public void yourMethod(){}}

Comment: It seems like you are explaining how to use a class in a program or am i confused?
I want to use a function that is not in the program its self.
Can you expand on what you are saying please as I do not understand it enough to grasp the point with brief comments. - Thanks